# jhipster request body search

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster

I have a JHipster project configured with ElasticSearch and I would like to use "Request Body search" instead "URI search".

I only see the REST method : "http://localhost:8080/api/_search/address/query=*" but I would like to send a body json.

Is there a way to do this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use your *AddressSearchRepository* which extends *ElasticsearchRepository*.
Just write your custom queries like:

```
List<Address> findByStreetnameAndNumber(String streetname, int number);
```

It will be converted to Elasticsearch queries automatically.

If you want to use JSON payload queries, use @Query annotation and write your JSON request there, like this:

```
public interface AddressSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Address, String> {
    @Query("{"bool" : {"must" : {"field" : {"name" : "?0"}}}}")
    Page<Address> findByName(String name,Pageable pageable); }
```

See the documentation: [Spring Data Elasticsearch @Query annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.at-query)

Comment: Here's a nice example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-elasticsearch-tutorial